# Dispatcher w/ Laravel duplicating output

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm lost on what I'm doing wrong, and I can't see anyone else with this problem, so it's gotta be me.

I've just setup `Indatus\Dispatcher\ServiceProvider` and have everything running just fine. For testing purposes, I'm just running a single scheduled event every 5 minutes to add a log entry.

For some reason, it's duplicating the log entries.

Here's what the output is looking like:

```
[2014-10-26 19:00:15] local.INFO: This is a test [] []
[2014-10-26 19:00:15] local.INFO: This is a test [] []
[2014-10-26 19:05:12] local.INFO: This is a test [] []
[2014-10-26 19:05:13] local.INFO: This is a test [] []
[2014-10-26 19:10:09] local.INFO: This is a test [] []
[2014-10-26 19:10:10] local.INFO: This is a test [] []
```

Here's the actual scheduled `fire()` event:

```
public function fire()
{
    Log::info('This is a test');
}
```

The `schedule()` :

```
public function schedule(Schedulable $scheduler)
{
    return $scheduler->everyMinutes(5);

}
```

and I've checked the `scheduled:summary` and it's only showing once:

```
+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------+------+--------------+-------+-------------+--------+
| Environment(s) | Name             | Args/Opts | Minute | Hour | Day of Month | Month | Day of Week | Run as |
+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------+------+--------------+-------+-------------+--------+
| *              | schedule:test    |           | */5    | *    | *            | *     | *           |        |
+----------------+------------------+-----------+--------+------+--------------+-------+-------------+--------+
```

And finally my crontab entry, which is only listed in the file once:

```
* * * * * php /vagrant/myapp/artisan scheduled:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I can't see any duplication that would cause it to run twice.

Any ideas what I've got wrong?

**Edit: **

As requested, full text from the test command:

use Indatus\Dispatcher\Scheduling\ScheduledCommand;
    use Indatus\Dispatcher\Scheduling\Schedulable;
    use Indatus\Dispatcher\Drivers\Cron\Scheduler;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

```
class NewSchedule extends ScheduledCommand {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'schedule:test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This is a test command';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * When a command should run
     *
     * @param Scheduler $scheduler
     * @return \Indatus\Dispatcher\Scheduling\Schedulable
     */
    public function schedule(Schedulable $scheduler)
    {
        return $scheduler->everyMinutes(5);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        Log::info('This is a test');
    }


}
```

Comment: Shouldnt be their only one > ?

Comment: Crondeamon maybe running twice ?

Comment: If you run `php artisan schedule:test` from the command line - does it only add one or two enteries to the log?

Comment: @JelleKeizer the dispatcher docs show two >

Comment: @TheShiftExchange from the command line it only runs once.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely the cron daemon having multiple processes spawned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to make sure that only one cron daemon is running, by issuing this command, from root:

```
ps aux | grep [c]ron
```

...and make sure there is only one result. If there are more, then multiple processes are running and triggering Dispatcher.

You can also make sure the Dispatcher crontab wasn't mistakenly added for multiple users (both `vagrant` and `root`, for example:

```
sudo ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

...to see what users have active `crontabs`. There should only be one result.

Comment: `ps aux | grep [c]ron` shows only the one item : `root       877  0.0  0.2  19104  1028 ?        Ss   13:53   0:05 cron`; checking crontab there's only one entry as well.

Comment: Run `sudo ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs` and post the output...I'm guessing it reads `root  vagrant`?

Comment: That means you have 2 crontabs running—one for the `root` user, and one for the `vagrant` user. Both of them are probably running the dispatcher...check the `vagrant` crontab and remove the `* * * * * php /vagrant/myapp/artisan scheduled:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1` line.

Comment: ...or, better yet, remove the `vagrant` user's crontab altogether. Login as `vagrant` (or `su vagrant` if you're logged in as `root`), and type `crontab -r`.

Comment: hmm... looking into this. I'm loging in as vagrant user (as is default with vagrant) and i'm not actually sure how to login as root... will look into this as a possibility

Comment: The docs for Dispatcher instruct you to add the `scheduled:run` command to the *root* crontab, using `sudo crontab -e`. If you do that (while logged in as `vagrant`), and then at some later point type `crontab -e` without the `sudo`, you can end up creating a second crontab for user `vagrant`. You can check the contents of both crontabs by running `sudo crontab -l` to see what's in `root`, and `crontab -l` (without `sudo`) to see what's in `vagrant`. Only *one* of them should have the Dispatcher call.

Comment: Sneaky buggers, those crontabs...glad to help!